# How to get the list of edge attributes of a Networkx graph

Tags: python-3.x, networkx

I would like to know if there is any function to get the list of node/edge attributes of a Networkx graph

The function [`get_node_attributes`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.classes.function.get_node_attributes.html#networkx.classes.function.get_node_attributes)/[`get_edge_attributes`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.classes.function.get_edge_attributes.html) returns the attribute values when the attribute name is specified. But I'd like to know how to get the attribute names of a weighted graph.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Both `Graph.nodes` and `Graph.edges` take a `data` parameter, which if set to `True` we get the node/edge attributes returned in a tuple as `(n, dict[data])`, where the second term is a dictionary containing all attributes. Here's an example:

```
G = nx.Graph()

G.add_node(2, lat=41.793780, long=3.972440)
G.add_node(4, lat=41.151363, long=54.374512)
G.add_node(5, lat=17.164215, long=13.92541)
G.add_node(6, lat=10.173651, long=30.335611)

G.add_edge(2, 4, weight=0.2, length=12)
G.add_edge(5, 6, weight=0.6, length=13)
```

By setting `data=True` as mentioned, we get:

```
G.nodes(data=True)
NodeDataView({2: {'lat': 41.79378, 'long': 3.97244}, 
              4: {'lat': 41.151363, 'long': 54.374512}, 
              5: {'lat': 17.164215, 'long': 13.92541}, 
              6: {'lat': 10.173651, 'long': 30.335611}})

G.edges(data=True)
EdgeDataView([(2, 4, {'weight': 0.2, 'length': 12}), 
              (5, 6, {'weight': 0.6, 'length': 13})])
```

If you only want a list with the attribute names of say, the edges, you could do:

```
from itertools import chain

set(chain.from_iterable(d.keys() for *_, d in G.edges(data=True)))
# {'length', 'weight'}
```

Or in the simpler case in which we have the same attributes for each edge:

```
list(list(G.edges(data=True))[0][-1].keys())
# ['weight', 'length']
```

Comment: Could you add a few commands to extract the attribute names?  Probably use a set and union over all of the edges.  Since each edge could have attributes not included in other edges I don't think there is a faster way to do it in general, though if we know it's the same for all edges, we could just look at the keys for one edge.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'd like to check whether a given attribute name, say `weight` or `length` is present in `EdgeDataView`.

Comment: @natasha - can you assume that all edges have the same attributes?  [in general in networkx each edge could have attributes that other edges do not]

Comment: Sure will update @Natasha Thx for your suggestions joel, sounds like the way to go

Comment: @Joel Yes, all the edges of my graph have the same attributes.